# isolating a <div> element from a window Object reference

Tags: javascript

So I have the following reference to a `window` object.

```
var myWindowRef = window.open('html-page.html', etc.)
```

I would like to grab, from the particular window, a reference to one of the child `<div>` within that HTML document by using the `<div>`'s id. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You'd just access it in the same way that you'd use in the current window.

Answer (score 1):

assuming it is in the same domain

`myWindowRef.document.getElementById('id');`